# Free jqGrid - Showing/Hiding columns if empty

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to show or hide columns depending if the columns contain data in Free jqGrid version 4.14.1.  Data feed is from server database in JSON format.

First, I have a colModel which displays all possible columns.

```
colModel: [
            {name:'consultation', label:'Consultation 3'},
            {name:'diagnosis', label:'Diagnosis', formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:'prescription', label:'Prescription', formatter:fancyBoxFormatter}, 
            {name:'tests', label:'Tests', formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:'imaging', label:'Imaging', formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:'generic', label:'Generic', formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:'referral', label:'Referral', formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:'management', label:'Management', formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:'completed', label:'Completed'}
                             ],
```

Then I set the cellvalue to empty if null in the custom formatter, fancyboxFormatter:

```
function fancyBoxFormatter(cellvalue, options) {
      if (cellvalue == '')
        return '';
    if (cellvalue == null || cellvalue == 'null')
        return '';
    return "<a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"#data" +
        options.rowId + "_" + options.colModel.name + "\">" + cellvalue + "</a>" +
        "<div style=\"display:none\"><div id=\"data" +
        options.rowId + "_" + options.colModel.name + "\">" +
        cellvalue + "</div></div>";
}
```

Then, do the hide/show bit, albeit with a defined column...

```
beforeProcessing: function (){
                             if($subgrid_3.jqGrid('getCol', 'prescription') == ''){
                             $subgrid_3.hideCol('prescription');
                             } else if($subgrid_3.jqGrid('getCol', 'prescription') !== ''){
                             $subgrid_3.showCol('prescription');
                             }
                         },
```

How can I change this to check all columns (i.e. rather than naming each one...) and show/hide if empty?

Comment: Please write in all your question about jqGrid **the version** and **the fork** of jqGrid, which you use. You want additionally to implement some logic based on **the data**, contained in the column. Thus it's important to know, whether you use **local data** (`datatype: "local"` or `datatype: "json"` with `loadonce: true`) or not. Should be the column hide/show based on contains of the data in the column on *the current page* or on the *whole data* (all pages) loaded in the grid.

Comment: Hi Oleg   http://130.95.21.121/vmd/evaluation/evaluation_7.php

Comment: Oleg, I have taken on board your points in my previous questions on my jqGrid project, especially about loading all data at once etc.  For this proof of concept, I just want to make sure that jqGrid can fulfill the functionality I need for the time being.  I'll then go back and review.

Comment: Sorry, if you post new question then you should think about the reader of *the question*. One don't need to read all your previous questions. Moreover the best solution of your problem depend on the `datatype`. If you loads the data from the server then you should use `beforeProcessing`, test the data loading from the server and call `hideCol`/`showCol` inside of `beforeProcessing`. The usage of `getCol` inside of `gridComplete` is much more slowly.

Comment: Oleg, thanks.  I have put the hide/show code in a beforeProcessing function, too little data to make it noticeably faster. Code updated as per link above. Now, can you see  a better way or iterating through the columns to check if empty?  Thanks again for your invaluable assistance ;)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any changes in the code of your question. Where is the code of `beforeProcessing`? I'm not sure that I understand your question about iterating through the columns. `beforeProcessing` has parameter with full data returned from the server. Iteration over the data is easy and very quickly, but it depends on the format of the data returned from the server. You should just return the data from the server in the format, which you can better to analyse.

Comment: Oleg, sorry, I  meant the demo link above i.e. http://130.95.21.121/vmd/evaluation/evaluation_7.php  Also updated this in the OP code.  To restate, I am specifying the getCol with the name of a certain column as an example, is there a better way to go through all the columns without the need to specify each column with getCol name?

Comment: Sorry, but we don't understand us. Stackoverflow isn't a forum where somebody help you. The goal is sharing of **common questions**, which could have some value for other visitors, and **the solutions** (or best practice) of the problems. You should always think about other readers of your question. The code of `beforeProcessing`, which you posted now has no sense. `getCol` uses [**unformatter**](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting), which you not defined and it's at least 100 or 1000 times slowly as access of JavaScript data.

Comment: Just replace `beforeProcessing: function (){...}` to `beforeProcessing: function (data) {...}` and iterate over the `data` returned from the server. You can extend the format of the data returned from the server *in any way*, to simplify the analyse inside of `beforeProcessing`. It would be very helpfuf for other readers if you include **test data** returned from the server in the text of your question. The code of `beforeProcessing` will be full based on the format of the data.

Comment: For example, you can test `data.rows[i].referral` for all items in the `data.rows` array and to hide the column if all `data.rows[i].referral` has falsy values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use `beforeProcessing` to analyse the data returned from the server. The code of `beforeProcessing` will heavy depend on the format of data returned from the server. Below is an example of `beforeProcessing`:

```
beforeProcessing: function (data) {
    var i, foundPrescription = false;
    if (data.rows != null) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.rows.length) {
            if (data.rows[i].prescription) { // if not empty string
                foundPrescription = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        $(this).jqGrid(foundPrescription ? "showCol" : "hideCol", "prescription");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this via css.
You can use the :empty selector or just add via javascript a class like "hidden" and set in the .css file ".hidden{display:none;}".

This should do the trick

Comment: Alex Wink@ That may work, but I can already show/hide columns with the jqGrid functionality, showCol and hideCol. The question more relates to looping through all columns and performing some action if empty or not, i.e. without specifying each column, I could do that, but would prefer a better way.